# Multiple RadioButtons with one selectable value

Tags: java, android

So I'm have two RadioGroups, one for gender, one for unit type. User has to select value for both RadioGroups, but value of first selected group affects the value of secont group.

For example, if user is male and uses metric unit type one layout will be shown to him. If he's male but uses imperial unit, another layout will be shown to him.

My question is, how to have RadioButton onClick method inside of RadioButton onClick method?

Sorry, I don't know how to explain this better.

Here's the code:

```
public void dialogBodyFatMuskarciRadioButtonKliknut(View view){
            boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
            switch (view.getId()){
                case R.id.radioButtonDialogBodyFatSpolMuski:
                    if (checked)
                        public void dialogBodyFatRadioMetrickaJedinica(View view){
                    boolean checked = ((RadioButton) view).isChecked();
                    switch (view.getId()){
                        case R.id.radioButtonDialogBodyFatSpolMuski:
                            if (checked)
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Didnt test this, but you could implement the logic something like this.

In your Manifest:

```
<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/gender_RadioGroup"
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/male"
        android:text="@string/male"
        android:onClick="onGenderRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/female"
        android:text="@string/female"
        android:onClick="onGenderRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>

<RadioGroup xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/unit_type_RadioGroup"
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/metric_unit_type"
        android:text="@string/metric_unit_type"
        android:onClick="onMetricRadioButtonClicked"/>
    <RadioButton android:id="@+id/imperial_unit_type"
        android:text="@string/imperial_unit_type"
        android:onClick="onMetricRadioButtonClicked"/>
</RadioGroup>
```

You would need to maintain the View instance of `view_gender` and `view_unit_type` inside your class. onCreate is a good place to do it using findViewById.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {    
    view_gender = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.gender_RadioGroup);
    view_unit_type = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.unit_type_RadioGroup);
}

public void onGenderRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    if(((RadioButton) view).isChecked())
        chooseLayout(view, view_unit_type );
}

public void onMetricRadioButtonClicked(View view) {
    if(((RadioButton) view).isChecked())
        chooseLayout(view_gender, view);
}

public void chooseLayout(View View1, View View2){
    if (View1.getId()==R.id.male && View2.getId()==R.id.metric_unit_type)
        // show male metric type layout
    else if (View1.getId()==R.id.male && View2.getId()==R.id.imperial_unit_type)
        // show male imperial type layout
    else if (View1.getId()==R.id.female && View2.getId()==R.id.metric_unit_type)
        // show female metric type layout
    else
        // show female imperial type layout
}
```